# magento - add customer name to order grid in magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to add a new `column` for Customer Name in the Sales Order Grid located here:

```
App/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php
```

I want add Customer Name like Name in Manage Customers.

I have added the following code:

```
protected function _getCollectionClass()
{
    return 'sales/order_grid_collection';
}

protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    /*junpeng add start*/

    $collection->getSelect()
    ->join(
    'customer_entity',
    'main_table.customer_id = customer_entity.entity_id', array('email' => 'email'));

    $collection->getSelect()->join(
    'customer_entity_varchar',
    'main_table.entity_id = customer_entity_varchar.entity_id', array('name' => 'value')
    );

    /*junpeng add end*/
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Customer Name'),
        'index' => 'name',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('email', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('Sales')->__('Customer Email'),
        'index'     => 'email',
        'type'        => 'text',
    ));
}
```

Customer Email is OK,but add Customer Name does not work it!

Can someone please help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't get customer name in just one line code join. Firstname and Lastname are different attributes and you will need to join them with your original collection and then concatenate them to display as Fullname.

So basically, Replace

```
$collection->getSelect()->join(
    'customer_entity_varchar',
    'main_table.entity_id = customer_entity_varchar.entity_id', array('name' => 'value')
    );
```

with this code

```
$fn = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('1', 'firstname');
$ln = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('1', 'lastname');
$collection->getSelect()
    ->join(array('ce1' => 'customer_entity_varchar'), 'ce1.entity_id=main_table.customer_id', array('firstname' => 'value'))
    ->where('ce1.attribute_id='.$fn->getAttributeId()) 
    ->join(array('ce2' => 'customer_entity_varchar'), 'ce2.entity_id=main_table.customer_id', array('lastname' => 'value'))
    ->where('ce2.attribute_id='.$ln->getAttributeId()) 
    ->columns(new Zend_Db_Expr("CONCAT(`ce1`.`value`, ' ',`ce2`.`value`) AS customer_name"));
```

And replace your `addColumn('name',` code in `_prepareColumns` method where you are getting the customer name, with this:

```
$this->addColumn('customer_name', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Customer Name'),
        'index' => 'customer_name',
        'filter_name' => 'customer_name'
    ));
```

Comment: Thank you for help!I test your code then have a problem.If the person does Not LOGGED IN,all of the information will not display in your code.

Comment: @JasonCheng I doubt it. We are not getting any value from customer's session so this can't be problem. Also this is for backend grid, so customer's login is not considered here.

Comment: Hi kalpesh..I used above code in my custom module grid and it gave me this error---- Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'customer_name' in 'where clause',..... Do you know where I can be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free magento extension for this:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/enhanced-admin-grids-editor.html

It's currently alpha, but I have tested it and it works perfectly on 1.6 and 1.7!

Answer (score 0):

I inspire my answer from Kalpesh
so you should replace this code

```
$collection->getSelect()->join(
'customer_entity_varchar',
'main_table.entity_id = customer_entity_varchar.entity_id', array('name' => 'value')
);
```

with these lines

```
$customerTable = Mage::getResourceSingleton('customer/customer')->getEntityTable();
$firstnameAttribute=Mage::getResourceSingleton('customer/customer')->getAttribute('firstname');

$firstnameAttributeTable = $firstnameAttribute->getBackend()->getTable();

$lastnameAttribute=Mage::getResourceSingleton('customer/customer')->getAttribute('lastname');
$lastnameAttributeTable = $lastnameAttribute->getBackend()->getTable();
$collection->getSelect()
->join( array('customer_varchar1'=>$firstnameAttributeTable),'main_table.customer_id =customer_varchar1.entity_id and customer_varchar1.attribute_id='.$firstnameAttribute->getId(),
        array('customer_varchar1.value'))
    ->join( array('customer_varchar2'=>$lastnameAttributeTable),'main_table.customer_id =customer_varchar2.entity_id and customer_varchar2.attribute_id='.$lastnameAttribute->getId(),
        array('customer name'=>'CONCAT(customer_varchar2.value ," " ,customer_varchar1.value)'));
```